# upload xls file to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to upload an excel file to the web server then open it up to read the tables to a listbox then select the listbox and reopen the excel file to bind the data to a gridview.

```
   //upload file to web server - this works fine
    protected void getFile()
    {
        string importPL = string.Empty;

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName); 
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName); 

            if (StaticHelpers.getApplicationEnvironment() == "D")
            {
                //dev
                importPL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devPL"];
            }
            else if (StaticHelpers.getApplicationEnvironment() == "T")
            {
                //test
                importPL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["devPL"];
            }
            else
            {
                //prod
                importPL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodPL"];
            }

            if ((extension == ".xls" || extension == ".xlsx"))
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName); 
                fileName = fileInfo.Name;
                string excelFilePath = importPL; 

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelFilePath + fileName);

                SpreadSheet = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;   
                SpreadSheet = excelFilePath + fileName;

                lblss.Text = SpreadSheet; 
                lblSpreadSheet.Text = "SpreadSheet: " + SpreadSheet.ToString(); 

                if (SpreadSheet.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ArrayList strTables = GetTableExcel(SpreadSheet);//get list of worksheets then bind to listbox
                        lstbxWorksheets.DataSource = strTables;
                        lstbxWorksheets.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //get list of worksheets I believe this is where I'm having most of my problems
    public static ArrayList GetTableExcel(string strFileName)
    {
        ArrayList strTables = new ArrayList();
        Catalog oCatlog = new Catalog();
        ADOX.Table oTable = new ADOX.Table();
        ADODB.Connection oConn = new ADODB.Connection();
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";
        try
        {
            oConn.Open(connectionString);
            oCatlog.ActiveConnection = oConn;
            if (oCatlog.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                int item = 0;
                foreach (ADOX.Table tab in oCatlog.Tables)
                {
                    if (tab.Type == "TABLE")
                    {
                        strTables.Add(tab.Name);
                        item++;
                    }
                }
            }
    oConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
        return strTables;
    }


    //select the worksheet from the list box
    protected void lstbxWorksheets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            WorkSheet = lstbxWorksheets.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lblWorkSheet.Text = "Worksheet: " + WorkSheet;

            SpreadSheet = lblss.Text;
            tableName = WorkSheet;

            if (tableName != string.Empty)
            {
                SelectedTable = tableName;
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Select a worksheet.";
            }

            if ((SelectedTable != string.Empty) && (SelectedTable != null))
            {
                DataTable dt = GetDataTableExcel(SpreadSheet, SelectedTable);

                gvData.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                gvData.DataBind();
                WorkSheet = SelectedTable.ToString();
            }
    }

    //get data from workbook and bind to gridview
    public static DataTable GetDataTableExcel(string strFileName, string Table)
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strFileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + Table + "]";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

I even added this to the web.config:

```
<location path="pl">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: It looks like you forget to add question... Side note: please consider significantly decreasing size of your sample code and adding error/problem information (unless you just want to share the code, in which case this simply will be deleted).

Answer (score 1):

sorry in aspnet
see with jet engine like in this project
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8096/C-Retrieve-Excel-Workbook-Sheet-Names

Comment: And how this suggestion relates to ASP.Net tag?

Comment: everything im doing and in that article works fine locally but not on the web server. any ideas why? permissions? do i need excel installed on the web server?

Comment: think i got it by modifying com settings - since this is an excel file -- com, my computer permissions - allow service account access